# How to create a zipfile with child zipFiles in php

Tags: php, symfony

i need to create a zipFile with a childs zipFiles already exist :

```
> folder
  - file1.zip
  - file2.zip
```

I want to get a zip file containing all the zip files in the folder.

```
$dir = "path/to/my/dir";
$finder = new Finder();
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

/***** I create a empty zip file ****/
$filesystem->dumpFile("$dir/delivrables.zip",'');

if($zip->open('delivrables.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    foreach ($finder->in($dir) as $file) { 
        $zip->addFile($file->getPath(), $file->getFilename());
    }
}
```

I don't get error but i can't extract zip file.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: What actually is your question ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a zip file with zip files in the same way as you create a zip file with images, documents etc